# geocoder address.getLocality() is often empty or wrong

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, android-location

I try to reverse geocoding this lat/lng via geocoder :

```
longitude: 14.4183926
Latitude: 50.0276543
```

But this return me via `geocoder.getFromLocation()` some address that do not contain the city OR that contain the sublocality in place of the city:

```
address.getLocality() => return Praha 4 (instead of Praha)
```

but when i try via google maps api directly :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50.0276543,14.4183926&language=cs
```

we can see :

```
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "26B",
           "short_name" : "26B",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "1765",
           "short_name" : "1765",
           "types" : [ "premise" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Psohlavců",
           "short_name" : "Psohlavců",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Braník",
           "short_name" : "Braník",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Praha 4",
           "short_name" : "Praha 4",
           "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Praha",
           "short_name" : "Praha",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Česko",
           "short_name" : "CZ",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "147 00",
           "short_name" : "147 00",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ]
```

So it's seam that address.getLocality() return sublocality instead of locality.

so is their anyway to retrieve from geocoder the correct value for **getLocality()** or at least to access the **address_components** ?

Comment: If you want what the Geocoding web service gives you, why not call that from your app instead?

Comment: finally it's what's i did ...